# How to make a toggle variable persist?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a quiz page where I have a timer that I would like to be able to toggle on or off so it doesn't distract the user, and save the setting after submitting an answer. The timer function works, and calls on localStorage.getItem(). But when I try the below with a boolean to see if the showHideTimer() button is clicked, the timer always shows up when the next question appears. The console always logs true when the page loads a new question.

```
<script>
    var clickCookie = 'clicked';
    var clicked = localStorage.getItem(clickCookie);
    console.log(clicked);
    function showHideTimer(){
        if(clicked==true){
            document.getElementById("testHeaderRight").style.color = "black";
            clicked=false;
            localStorage.setItem(clickCookie, clicked);
            console.log(clicked);
            return clicked;
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("testHeaderRight").style.color = "white";
            clicked=true;
            localStorage.setItem(clickCookie, clicked);
            console.log(clicked);
            return clicked;
        }
    };
    window.onload = function(){
        if(clicked===null){
            localStorage.setItem(clickCookie, false);
        } else {
            showHideTimer(clickCookie);
        }
    };
</script>
<body>
   <button id="showHideTimer" onclick="showHideTimer()">Toggle Timer</button>
   <div id="testHeaderRight">
            Time Remaining :
            <span id="time"></span>
   </div>
<script>
        var cookieName = 'startTimer';
        var savedSeconds = localStorage.getItem(cookieName);
        function startTimer(duration, display) {
        var timer = duration, seconds;
        setInterval(function () {
            seconds = parseInt(timer);
            display.textContent = secondsToHms(seconds);
            var runningTime = (parseInt(seconds));
            localStorage.setItem(cookieName, runningTime);
        }, 1000);
    }
    
    window.onload = function () {
        var startTime = 7200,
        display = document.querySelector('#time');
        if (savedSeconds === null){
            startTimer(startTime, display);
        } else {
            startTimer(savedSeconds, display);
        }
    };
</script>
</body>
```

I've tried moving the window.onload call into the same function as the timer since that is functioning properly, but seems to make no difference. I've tried switching the clicked=true/false; variables around to make sure I'm not confusing myself with booleans, and they switch freely in the console when clicking on the button. I've tried changing the return value of the showHideTimer() function to be localStorage.setItem(clickCookie, clicked);

Comment: What's PHP got to do with this?

Comment: @j08691 its "What's PHP got to do, got to do with it?... Who needs an app when an app can be broken."

Answer (score 1):

When you get the item out of storage it's a string, `"true"`, not a boolean.

So your `if(clicked==true)` comparison never passes and you end up on the "false" path every time.

Comment: I've adjusted the code to be looking for strings now [if(clicked=="true")], but still no change when the page loads up, whether I set it to "true" or "false". The variable will display correctly from one page to the next, but the timer is still visible no matter what at the beginning of the page.